# Scroll both Left and Right divs by the Outer wrapper div vertically and Right div to Horizontal scroll - always visible

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I need only a Pure CSS Solution and No Jquery or Java script. Your help will be appreciated.

The Wrapper div will have a View height with a vertical scroll (which will scroll both the left and the right divs to scroll vertical).

Left and Right will always will be equally growing in Height. And the Right Div only will need to Horizontally scroll. Overflow-x: scroll and this should be Always visible the right div horizontal scroll.

HTML Code:

```
    <div class="main_wrap" style="padding-top:10px;">


        <div class="left">
              <!-- loop -->
              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>1</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>2</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>3</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>4</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>5</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>6</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>7</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>8</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>9</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>10</p>
              </div>
              <!-- loop -->          
        </div>



        <div class="chatRooms">

              <div class="each_cell">
                  <div class="render_box">
                    Box
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>2</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>3</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>4</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>5</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>6</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>7</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>8</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>9</p>
              </div>

              <div class="each_cell">
                <p>10</p>
              </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
    p{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    color:#fff !important;
    font-size:14px !important;
    line-height:19px !important;
    margin-bottom:9px !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

.each_cell{
  background:black;
  width:100%;
  height:39px;
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:3px;
}

.main_wrap {
    width:80%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #a0b5ba;
    min-height: 100%;    
    height: 80vh;    
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}

.left {
    background:red;
    width: 89px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}


.chatRooms{
    left:90px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.render_box{
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  left:1500px;
  position:relative;
}
```

[Please see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YB8X.jpg)

Comment: do you want to have horizontal scroll on  outer div?
I didnt get your question

Comment: I tried many its a bit complicating... No I dont want the Horizontal Div for the Outer Wrapper. 

But I need it for the inner Div that's the right Div to Horizontally scroll which will have a Long width..... 

Outer Wrapper when vertical scroll both left and Right divs should scroll vertically.   

Please see the example image attached.

Right now the logic is there, the problem is when I vertically scroll the Right div Horizontal scroll is getting covered. I want it to be always visible.

Comment: I dont think this case is possible with pure css. If you need horizontal scroll to be visible then you will need to put overflow property to child. But in that case it will will not scroll the left section. You will will need to create two scroll and when right or left scroll change the position then you will need to move vice versa. I will not suggest to do this kind of changes

Comment: Your right mate... I am fluent in UI/UX but humbly asked if someone may know which I missed. I tried all even in SASS but this is not possible. So I did use Jquery:

  $('.mydiv').scroll(function () {
                $(this).find('.fixedaxisy').css('left', $(this).scrollLeft());
            });

This worked... Thanks all for the time taken to answer.